# Measure of relatedness between two animals

Tags: genetics, pedigree

So I am aware there is such a thing as inbreeding coefficient which is a number allocated to an individual as a result of taking the average of it's parents' inbreeding coefficient.

(Note that I am working in terms of pedigree based relatedness, not genomic relatedness.)

Is there a number that quantifies the relationship level between 2 individuals?

If so how is this calculated? Can it be done in R using the pedigree package?

Where say a sire and ewe have a 0.5 value or something similar?

Comment: There are about an 25 thousands ways to measure relatedness between two individuals. The most obvious coming to mind  based on your description is the coefficient of relatedness. Relatedness is the probability that two individuals share an allele due to recent common ancestry. There are probably tens or hundreds of online tutorials. Consider [this one](http://ess.nbb.cornell.edu/relatedness.html) for example.

Comment: I believe a good word for what I am after is "kinship," or a "kinship matrix."

Comment: Consider having a look at the [kinship2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kinship2/kinship2.pdf) package.